# Magento 2: Custom product collection with layered navigation

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation, product-collection

How can we load custom product collection with layered navigation? Same like search result page but with custom product collection. I have checked here [Magento 2 - Layered Navigation for Custom Product Collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206609/magento-2-layered-navigation-for-custom-product-collection?rq=1) but still there is no any accepted answer.