# Magento 2 get Layered Navigation By Product Collection

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I need Layered Navigation Attribute Collection Based on Product Collection.

I have used Following Method it give Attribute List.

```
$filterableAttributes = $om->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);
$appState = $om->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$layerResolver = $om->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
$filterList = $om->create(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
    [
        'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
    ]
);

$category = 4;

$layer = $layerResolver->get();
$productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('application',11);

$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$layer->setProductCollection($productCollection);
$filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
```

Comment: Try this answer  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230777/48571

Comment: already try but it not working for me. in my case it not working.

Comment: @NiranjanGondaliya-Did you get any solution?

Comment: Yes i have use Layered Navigation in Rest API, I have get attribute and attribute assign option from products.